# I want to start at the same time more than one cucumber test with the help of watir-webdriver using tags. How can I get(start) it? Is it possible?

Tags: testing, cucumber, watir-webdriver

How can I get start it? Is it possible? Can you give me some simple example?
For example i use following command to launch defined tagged tests:
         **parallel_cucumber features/ -p [@critical]**
And all tests are launched after that, including untagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found :

```
 parallel_cucumber features --test-options '--tags @critical' .
```

Only features with tags @critical will be launched in this case.